# In what way are doc, info, man, help different?

Tags: documentation, manpage, helpfile, info

What's the difference between Documentation(doc), Manuals(man), Help, and Information(info)?

I've seen these four different words used across different system but mostly in Ubuntu. for the most part they seem to be interchangeable, but what is the difference between them or are they all the same?

This question might not belong here, if that's the case please tell me and I'll remove it.

Comment: This is a good question for [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/). Lets see if someone can move it for you.

Comment: I'm really not sure what your question is. Are you asking the difference between the English words? They're different uses in Ubuntu? The commands?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentation, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuals, don't know what you mean with help, and [info](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/) or texinfo.

Comment: He's talking about the difference between `man`, `info`, `/usr/share/*/doc` and Ubuntu Help. Not OT.

Comment: I was talking about the meanings as they stand in Ubuntu. So far I only know that man is manual pages and they contain simple usage information. I don't know about the rest.

Comment: @Lucio that might be correct though I'm not sure how to move something other than by deleting it.

Comment: I'm agree with @chaskes now. This question should stay here. Taylor, remember to mark an answer as accepted if it solve your issue.

Comment: @TaylorBioniks You would either: a, delete or close this one and ask it somewhere else, or b, flag it "other" and ask a moderator to migrate it to a different site. It's best to ask a moderator, because deleted and closed questions can count toward an automatic question ban (I'm not sure this applies to questions with a positive score or not, but it's best to be on the safe side right?). Anyhow, this should be fine here now that the misunderstanding is cleared up.

Comment: @Seth I think I'll just leave it, the answer for it was pretty good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Documentation**

   > [wiki on documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentation)

   In regard with Ubuntu, docs are located in `/usr/share/*/doc`. They can contain almost anything (html, txt, css ,png) the developers(or documentors) seem appropriate. Examples are licenses, tutorials, examples etc.
2. **Info**

   > [Wiki on Texinfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo)
   >   [GNU textinfo page](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/)
   >   [manpage for the `info` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/info)

   This command is invoked as

   ```
   info utility/function/program
   ```

   which will show the texinfo page for `utility` in info format.
3. **Man**

   > [Wiki on man page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page).
   >   [manpage for the `man` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/man)

   It is invoked as

   ```
   man utility/function/program
   ```

   This one is similar to `info`, but it has sections(1 to 9) and shows some colourful information.Unlike `info`, many  options are available to man in order to give as much flexibility as possible to the user. Note that `man` may have less information than `info`.
4. **Help**

   > [Wiki on help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help)

   It displays information about builtin commands in bash.It is very short description of the function/command.More on help in `help help`